# One to one relationships in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 databases named Users and Links. Whenever a new user signup, one collection is created in Users with unique id. What I want is to create another collection in Links with a field `userId`  that has id of the newly created user. Also I want the id of the new collection from Links to be added in the newly created user collection. How can I achieve this with `mongoose` and `mongodb`?

What I understood was to write 3 queries as follows:

```
const user = await User.create({req.body}) //comes from the client side
const link = await Link.create({userId: user._id})
const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: user._id}, {link: link._id})
```

**What I want to know, Is this the correct way?**

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly answering your question but you might want to reconsider your choice of database types. Since you're talking about querying by keys across multiple tables where records have some kind of relationship you might want to have a look at relationship databases like PostgreSQL for instance.